# java inherited spring autowired property is null

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

**EDIT:** My question is not about why Spring bean is null, but about why inherited bean is null? Proposed answer explains why new operator does not work with autowiring. But my question is about inheritance.
I have two classes:

```
@Transactional
public class A {

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    //other methods
}

public class B extends A {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    //other methods
}
```

In *Main.java* I get *NPE* - class B dont have access to property A((( And I dont understand why(((

```
A inst1 = new B(); - dont have access to body of B.
B inst2 = new B(); - inside class B sessionFactory is null(((
```

What I do wrong? I need to have access to body of B, and to properties of superior class. Bean sessionFactory is working:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionfactory = (SessionFactory) context.getBean("sessionFactory");
        Session session = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();//works
```

Comment: How can `propertyA` be null when it's declared as a primitive? Seems odd!

Comment: it should work fine .. you have some other mistakes i guess

Comment: Post some real code so we can verify your problem.

Comment: post whole code please

Comment: If I do A inst3 = new A() - it is not null. It is simplified code. Classes have more methods. I just skipped them.

Comment: B will not have access to a protected member of A if it is not in the same package.

Comment: post the full stack trace / Exception

Comment: Results of my testing:

      public class A {
            protected int propertyA = 1;
        }
        
        public class B extends A{
            public int propertyB = propertyA + 1;
            
            public static void main(String[] args) {
             A inst1 = new B(); 
             B inst2 = new B(); 
             System.out.println(inst1.propertyA); // prints 1
             System.out.println(inst2.propertyB);  // prints 2
         }
        }

How do you have null?

Comment: I thought I do smth wrong. Ok. I will edit it.

Comment: The object returned by `new B()` has no relation to Spring. There's no way for Spring to inject anything into it. Why would you expect any `@Autowired` annotated fields to be non-`null`?

Comment: ***1.*** Spring will not magically inject the property for you when you are `new`ing your object instance manually.  Your instance of `B` needs to be created/managed by Spring ***2.*** I have no clue on your meaning of "*class B dont have access to property A*".  I cannot see any "property A".  Be precise and clear when you ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting NPE, is because `sessionFactory` is not being injected, instead that you haven't access to `sessionFactory` property.

If you can get an instance of `sessionFactory` after loading your application context, then this bean is right configured.

So I believe your problem has to be related with autowired annotation config. Do you have `<context:annotation-config />` into your application context? or have you got a bean of class `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` defined into your application context?
 - Has your beans xml node